# Can't get selected item in Angular 2 form

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm learning Angular 2 (4), and I have a little problem with an Angular form. The problem is that I can't retrieve values of item from database when I select that item in a dropdown list. So in my case I can't retrieve values of "Brand" when I select that "Brand" in a dropdown list.

This is my "Brand" Model:

```
 public class Brand
{
    [Required]
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    //Relation
    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    public Brand()
    {
        Cars = new Collection<Car>();collection
    }
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
       [HttpGet("/api/brands")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<BrandResource>> GetBrands()
    {
        var brands = await context.Brands.Include(m => m.Cars).ToListAsync();
        return mapper.Map<List<Brand>, List<BrandResource>>(brands);
    }
```

My Mapping Profile:

```
 public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Brand, BrandResource>();
        CreateMap<CarType, CarTypeResource>();
        CreateMap<Car, CarResource>();
    }
```

My Service for getting Brands:

```
@Injectable()
export class VehicleService {

constructor(private http: Http ) { }

getBrands(){
return this.http.get('/api/brands')
.map(res => res.json());
}

}
```

My component in which I try to log values of selected brand:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-vehicle-form',
templateUrl: './vehicle-form.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./vehicle-form.component.css']
})
export class VehicleFormComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(
private vehicleService: VehicleService) { }
brands: any[];
cars: any[];
cartypes: any[];
vehicle: any = {};

ngOnInit() {
this.vehicleService.getBrands().subscribe(brands => 
  this.brands = brands

);

}

onBrandChange(){
var selectedBrand = this.brands.find(b => b.BrandId == this.vehicle.brand);
    console.log(selectedBrand);

}
}
```

And finally my Form:

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="brand">Brand</label>
<select id="brand" class="form-control" (change)="onBrandChange()"    [(ngModel)]="vehicle.brand" name="brand">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option *ngFor="let b of brands" value="{{ b.BrandId }}">{{ b.name }}</option>
</select>
</div> 
</form>
```

So what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I tried to log Vehicle:

```
  onBrandChange(){
  console.log("VEHICLE", this.vehicle);
  }
```

and this is what I get:
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgDeB.png)

I think I should get something like this: **Object{brand:"1"}**. Does anybody know what might to be the problem?

Comment: What's happening? How is it not working? Are you seeing an error?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I just get ''undefined'' in my console when I select some Brand in a dropdown list.

Comment: Tried your code and worked fine for me, could you try and reproduce the issue in a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ngModel` so your `change` event will not work you should be using `ngModelChange` which will trigger the event `onBrandChange()` and you are missing the `ngValue`

```
<select id="brand" class="form-control" (ngModelChange)="onBrandChange()" 
        [(ngModel)]="vehicle.brand" name="brand">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option *ngFor="let b of brands" ngValue="{{ b.BrandId }}">{{ b.name }}</option>
</select>
```